# Visa for Dubai stopover

Tags: visas, transit-visas, uk-citizens, uae, dxb

Travelling to Delhi on British passport  have visa for India do I need visa for 1 day 2hours stopover /in transit to Dubai.?
Travelling  on Emirates airline

Answer (score 3):

British citizens do not need a visa to visit Dubai in the first place, as stated by the [UAE MFA](http://www.mofa.gov.ae/EN/ConsularServices/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx). So you certainly won't need it to change planes